# Find out what functions a static C library has

Tags: c, static-libraries, dump, disassembly

I have a static C library (say `mylib.a`) and I was wondering if it's possible to find out what functions are implemented inside that file. I don't have a corresponding header file. what I need is like the equivalent of [`javap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) for Java.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

On Windows you can use `dumpbin`.  On Linux and friends you can use `nm`.

Comment: nm works with both dynamic (libfoo.so) and static (libbar.a) libraries

Answer (score 36):

Use [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm). That will only give you the symbol names - of which most of the symbols prefixed with `T` will be functions. Function arguments are not retained in the binary.